# What is the proper RDFa syntax for an Organization logo?

Tags: html, rdfa

Im trying to get my article pages to have valid RDFa, using Google's [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/).  Im having trouble getting it to accept the Organization logo.  It keeps complaining that "A value for the url field is required."  I've tried adding the logo url as "url", "src" and "content" as you can see below. Ive also tried putting an actual `<img>` tag there with property="logo", but I can't get rid of the error message. Has anyone solved this?

```
<div vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="Article">
    <h1 property="headline name">My Amazing Article Title</h1>
    <meta property="articleSection" content="Sports" />
    <meta property="image" content="https://www.example.com/image.jpg" />
    <meta property="datePublished dateModified" content="2020-01-13" />

    <span property="author publisher" typeof="Organization">
        <meta property="name" content="MyCompanyName" />
        <meta property="logo" src="https://www.example.com/logo.png" url="https://www.example.com/logo.png" content="https://www.example.com/logo.png" />
        <meta property="url" content="https://www.example.com/" />
    </span>

    <div property="articleBody">
        Bla bla bla
    </div>
</div>
```

To see the exact error you can copy and paste the above snippet into Google's tool to see what I see.  By the way, if I omit the logo entirely, Google complains that a logo is required.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
<div vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="Article">
    <h1 property="headline name">My Amazing Article Title</h1>
    <meta property="articleSection" content="Sports" />
    <meta property="image" content="https://www.example.com/image.jpg" />
    <meta property="datePublished dateModified" content="2020-01-13" />

    <span property="author publisher" typeof="Organization">
        <meta property="name" content="MyCompanyName" />
        <span property="logo" typeof="ImageObject">
            <meta property="url" content="https://www.example.com/logo.png" />
        </span>
        <meta property="url" content="https://www.example.com/" />
    </span>

    <div property="articleBody">
        Bla bla bla
    </div>
</div>
```